# Where to put properties files in a JSF application and how to load it with f:loadBundle tag?

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I tried to add properties files to my xhtml page in JSF by using `f:loadBundle` tag. 
I tried do it many times in different ways but nothing works 
(`prop_files/logowanie`, `prop_files.logowanie`).
I kept property files in WebContent/prop_files folder and xhtml files are in WebContent.

Please help me how to add properties to page. 
Maybe I keep this files in wrong folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basename of a f:loadBundle tag should be like a class name as the properties files is loaded by the class loader like this:

```
 <f:loadBundle basename="com.examples.messages" var="msgs"/>
```

The file extension should be .properties.

So place the file in your classpath for example in your src/java/com/examples/messages.properties